# How to know if my angular service is consuming reactive springboot

Tags: angular

I am working with Reactive Programming and I have a problem in Angular.

I try to explain.

I have the following component service that works I think correct.

```
export class WebService {
  private _refreshNeeded$ = new Subject<void>();
  subjectNotifier: Subject<null> = new Subject<null>();
  websiteUrl = 'http://localhost:9001/';
  url: string = 'http://localhost:9001/';
  urlPaged: string = 'http://localhost:9001/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getWebsites(): Observable<Ticker[]> {
    return this.http.get<Ticker[]>(this.websiteUrl);
  }

  get refreshNeeded$() {
    return this._refreshNeeded$;
  }

  getQuoteStream(): Observable<Ticker> {
    return new Observable<Ticker>((observer) => {    
      let eventSource = new EventSource(this.url);
      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        console.debug('Received event: ', event);
        let json = JSON.parse(event.data);
        observer.next(new Ticker(json['id'], json['symbol'], json['priceChange']));
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {        
        if(eventSource.readyState === 0) {
          console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
          eventSource.close();
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
        }
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Then my component part.

```
export class WebsiteListComponent implements OnInit {
    
    quoteArray: Ticker[] = [];
    pagination: boolean;
    page: number;
    size: number;

  constructor(private quoteReactiveService: WebsiteService, private quoteBlockingService: WebsiteService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.pagination = true;
    this.page = 0;
    this.size = 50;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.quoteReactiveService.refreshNeeded$
    .subscribe(
        () => this.requestQuoteStream()
    );
    this.requestQuoteStream();
  }

  resetData() {
    this.quoteArray = [];
  }

  requestQuoteStream(): void {
    this.resetData();
    let quoteObservable: Observable<Ticker>;
    if (this.pagination === true) {
      quoteObservable = this.quoteReactiveService.getQuoteStream();
    } else {
      quoteObservable = this.quoteReactiveService.getQuoteStream();
    }
    quoteObservable.subscribe(quote => {
      this.quoteArray.push(quote);
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }
    
}
```

And now HTML.

```
<tr *ngFor="let ticker of quoteArray">
    <td>ID :{{ticker.id}}</td>
    <td>SYMBOL: {{ticker.symbol}}</td>
    <td>PRICE: {{ticker.priceChange}}</td>
</tr>
```

I think that with an application Reactive you will be receive the list continuous because is not blocking.

[image]

This is the result that I am looking for but I need to receive always the data so I need to refresh the component every second to receive new data from service.

Could anyone solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.quoteReactiveService.refreshNeeded$
    .subscribe(
        () => this.requestQuoteStream()
    );
```

becomes:

```
this.quoteReactiveService.refreshNeeded$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$))
  .subscribe((refresh: boolean) => {
     if(refresh)
        this.requestQuoteStream()
  });
```

Where `componentDestroyed$` is:

```
 private componentDestroyed$ = new Subject<void>();
```

and takeUntil is a function imported from `from 'rxjs/operators'`. Logic here being that we keep piping the result as long as our component is alive and we will only call for a request quoteStream if it is true. Now, that being said, you should add some sort of timer there to make sure you don't keep spam calling your backend nonstop

Also don't forget to implement `OnDestory` and dispose of the `componentDestroyed` as so:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.componentDestroyed$.next();
    this.componentDestroyed$.complete();
  }
```

Comment: I try you solution but I don't know how to implement it  :(